# how to control switch (proteus) using bluetooth card (HC-05) and arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, switch

This is the first time I use the Internet with the Arduino in the proteus ,
What are the stages that I must follow in order to be able to control the switch via Bluetooth?
If it was possible to clarify more, because I really do not know anything about the other applications, taht my first project in iot.
[image]

Comment: A switch is a mechanical device. It can only be controlled via bluetooth, if you add a motor, which presses the switch mechanically. Though that cannot be simulated in Proteus. Though I don't think this is, what you are really asking. The switch is connected to pin 2 of the Arduino. So you are reading the switch with your code. I guess you don't want to control the switch, but you want to control, what the switch is controlling via the code. So please include your code and explain, what exactly should happen on what serial data and what problems you have with doing that.

Comment: That sounds more like an essay question. I don't know Proteus really, but depending on how accurately it models reality, the HC-05 board needs VCC and GND wired.  Possibly others.